# Asp.Net Stopwatch C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, real-time, stopwatch

I have a web-based (ASP.NET C#) game platform that has a racecourse. Each user should complete this racecourse. When an online user starts the game, stopwatch starts to count and shows the time in simultaneously. I have a callback method and timer which calls this method every 1 minute. However, the problem is that while an online user is playing the game and other online user starts playing the game, stopwatch shows the time which is belong the first online user, however, it has to Show 0 for new online user. I cannot handle this problem. Do you have any idea without using javascript and jquery?

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use javascript or jquery?

Comment: It sounds like the stopwatch should be on the client side, as it's on a per-client basis.  I don't know why you're wanting to run it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have have to have a place to store the starttime for each player.
If you do not want to do that clientside - using javascript, you'll have to do it serverside, using the session cache.